!HELP MATLAB Code to test for oversampling and quantization
I am struggling to write a piece of M code to visualize the effect of the oversampling of a combined signal. This combined signal consists of two signals $x_1, x_2$ where both sit on the same spectrum but one with a higher power. In other words, one signal is a jamming signal of the other. I want to test whether by oversampling the combined signals and then quantization, I can write the following expressions:
$$Q[x_1,x_2] \approx Q[x_1] \ , \text{where $x_1$ is the jamming signal}$$
For now, I am referring to the code snippets provided in Modern Digital and Analog Communications by BP Lathi. Any hints and directions on how to get started are highly appreciated. Thank you.
